# subprocess.PIPE stays empty

Tags: python, logging, subprocess

Following some extensive research I came up with this code to call the music notation software MuseScore from Python 3.7 in order to convert files while saving MuseScore's conversion output to a logfile:

```
import subprocess

with open('conversion.log', 'w') as out:
    proc = subprocess.run(['mscore','-o','out.mscx','in.xml'], encoding='utf-8', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    for line in proc.stdout.split('\n'):
        out.write(line)`
```

The problem is: The logfile stays rigorously empty, no matter what I do. If I run the command in a terminal, however, MuseScore gives a lot of output.

Here is what I have tried as well:

The same thing put with one command argument only so that it can be run in a shell:

```
proc = subprocess.run("mscore -o out.mscx in.mxl", encoding='utf-8', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

And I tried the `capture_output` argument like this:

```
with open('conversion.log', 'wb', 0) as out:
    proc = subprocess.run(['mscore','-o','out.mscx','in.xml'], capture_output=True)
    out.write(proc.stdout)
```

All yielding empty files. Any ideas why?

Comment: Are you sure `mscore` actually writes to stdout?

Comment: Especially when you're using `-o out.mscx`, which seems to specify an output file. If you're trying to capture log output, that usually goes to stderr.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions! I am not sure mscore writes to stdout - probably that is the root of the problem. How can I find out? As I wrote, when I call it in the terminal, there is a lot of output in the terminal so I simply assumed that I was seeing things written to stdout/stderr. Both are routed to PIPEs in my code, btw. Do you know how to find out about the nature of a program's output?